# Facebook Application Canvas Page not loading

Tags: facebook

I have developed an app using PHP. The app works correctly when launched using the canvas url, but when launched using the application (canvas page), the app is not loading.

Connection timed out is only coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you are using HTTPS in the Facebook URL (**https**://apps.facebook.com/yourapp) and your server doesn't support HTTPS. Try accessing your app without the HTTPS in the URL.

Comment: I tried loading using HTTP, but Facebook automatically converts http to https!

Comment: Turn off `Secure Browsing` from your Account Settings and try again (found under `Account Settings` > `Security` > `Secure browsing`).